# CMD.exe write bat file with multiple commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, echo

I try to create bat file with cmd.exe and add pause command, but cmd.exe then write to bat file "Press any key to continue . . ."

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd\ & C: & echo "C:\windows\notepad.exe" & pause > test.bat
```

final bat file should contain:

```
"C:\windows\notepad.exe" & pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to create the batch file :

```
echo "C:\windows\notepad.exe\" ^& pause>> C:\test.bat
```

Why do you have to use cmd.exe to create a batch file?

If you have to use the command which you had asked in the question then format it like this:

```
echo exit | C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd\ & echo "C:\windows\notepad.exe\" ^& pause>> C:\test.bat
```

Comment: Thanks it works! :) I need create bat via cmd for install setup. Is there way to create bat with multiple lines?

Comment: You will have to **echo** the lines into the target batch file using >> .. same way as done in the above command.

Comment: aha i see ">>" this will append file, i used before ">" which will overwrite old file thanks :)